# evaluation metrics of MSE,MAE and RMSE

Tags: regression, random-forest, mse

I work on an image-regression model and I got these evaluation metrics for `RandomForestRegressor`. Are they good or not?

Test set evaluation:

---

- MAE: 13.489656084656085
- MSE: 1261.4647790063382
- RMSE: 35.51710544239688
- R2 Square 0.9972747098144139

---

Train set evaluation:

---

- MAE: 4.49049505406027
- MSE: 202.4055299189369
- RMSE: 14.226929743234725
- R2 Square 0.9995664291210042

Do the  metrics show a good result or not?

Comment: You can add context to get a more accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

Metrics pertinence depends on the context. For example if the small errors matters less than the big errors, MSE is good because as the error gets small, the mse gets even smaller, and when the error grows, MSE grows even bigger ( picture the square function graph in your head). If you want to penalize errors poportionally to their size without additional increase, MAE is better. See [RMSE or MAE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48267/mean-absolute-error-or-root-mean-squared-error) on *Cross-Validated* for more details.
Moreover, each metric scale depends on the specific problem : for example, a MSE value around 10 for predicting values in the range `[0,20]` is very bad, while the same MSE for predicting values in the range `[0, 1 000 000]` is very good.

However, you can see that errors on the train set are far lower than error on the test set. This is a clear sign of [**overfitting**](https://www.ibm.com/topics/overfitting), which is very bad and not desired at all.

Taken independently of overfitting, Wether the *test* errors you get are good or not depends on how precise you want to get, and how large the desired values can be. From my experience, a MSE of `100` is good when values are ranging inside `[0, 10 000]` (error of 1%).
However, in your case, the showcased results are very likely to be bad, because overfitting is bad.

Comment: i do more augmentation and now result is Test set evaluation:
_____________________________________
MAE: 244.6675961126774
MSE: 76306.22164454253
RMSE: 276.2358080418658
R2 Square 0.8351467275124113
__________________________________
====================================
Train set evaluation:
_____________________________________
MAE: 232.40407245326142
MSE: 75181.06250820357
RMSE: 274.19165287842657
R2 Square 0.8389553913444456  test is high but difference between train and test is so low it is good now or not?

Comment: @ErfanMollai read my answer, read the provided link, and then post a clearer question, as specified in my answer.

Comment: More specifically, think about 1. Why is lower error on training set than on test set means overfitting ? 2. What is the expected value of the prediction ? How big is the MSE compared to it ?